# how to use google signin in my website?

Tags: html, google-app-engine

Basically i am trying to use google signin in my website, and with my research i had i found google's official tutorial here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in and in this tutorial it says by adding g-signin2 div tag it will automatically create the whole button with text and image, but here in my code i doesn't even get the div itself created

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="googlesigninclient_id" content="818358372597-t5jrb0e9p4ivstp9mfi972lhcvfcuo59.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
</script>
</head>
</body>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

and i found this tutorial codexworld.com/login-with-google-account-using-javascript which doesn't work in my computer, although i am using latest version of chrome firefox and opera, but when i ran the same exact code at https://jsfiddle.net/h6q9vr2s/ it appears to be working just perfect.

here is source for tutorial

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Login with Google Account using JavaScript by CodexWorld</title>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="921258372597-t5jrb0e9p4ivstp9mfi972lhcvfcuo59.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="JquerySock.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
<script>
function onSuccess(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        //Display the user details
        request.execute(function (resp) {
            var profileHTML = '<div class="profile"><div  class="head">Welcome '+resp.name.givenName+'! <a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a></div>';
            profileHTML += '<img src="'+resp.image.url+'"/><div  class="proDetails"><p>'+resp.displayName+'</p><p>'+resp.emails[0].value+'</p>   <p>'+resp.gender+'</p><p>'+resp.id+'</p><p><a href="'+resp.url+'">View Google+ Profile</a></p></div></div>';
            $('.userContent').html(profileHTML);
            $('#gSignIn').slideUp('slow');
        });
    });
}
function onFailure(error) {
    alert(error);
}
function renderButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
    });
}
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        $('.userContent').html('');
        $('#gSignIn').slideDown('slow');
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- HTML for render Google Sign-In button -->
<div id="gSignIn"></div>
<!-- HTML for displaying user details -->
<div class="userContent"></div>

<style>
.profile{
border: 3px solid #B7B7B7;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 350px;
background-color: #F7F7F7;
height: 160px;
}
.profile p{margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;}
.head{margin-bottom: 10px;}
.head a{float: right;}
.profile img{width: 100px;float: left;margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;}
.proDetails{float: left;}
</style>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add google sign in to a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194571/how-to-add-google-sign-in-to-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using the APIs of the respective services (Google, Facebook, Twitter) or may be OpenID if you plan to add that as well. Some links:

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

http://openid.net/add-openid/

Also take a look here. There are several similar questions already present on SO, check the related questions on the right.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="818358372597-t5jrb0e9p4ivstp9mfi972lhcvfcuo59.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
<script>

function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
</script>
</head>
</body>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Its seems you are missing to `google-signin-client_id` to `googlesigninclient_id`rename it

Comment: Refer this page http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-account-using-javascript/

Comment: thanks for the link, could you read my question again, i updated my question

Comment: can send me the console out put?

Comment: here is my console output: cb=gapi.loaded_1:63 Uncaught gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

Comment: Have you provided the localhost as the redirect url in your app-key configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122039/discussion-between-mohamed-nizar-and-jacky).

Comment: you mean in my google developer console, i honestly don't know what that is

Comment: Yes! go and change the it to localhost!

Comment: Go through with Google developer Console Documentations

Comment: i just added the redirect uri to http://localhost/signin.jsp, but the thing is that i doesn't even get the button itself

Comment: did you add with http://localhost/ with port if is 8080 add http://localhos:8080/localtion

Comment: first i did tried adding the port number, second i don't think it would something to do with the port number cause here in my browser it doesn't even create the button, can you try in your own browser so you could see the output yourself.